# Fortran 90 read file

Tags: fortran

I am getting my hands wet with Fortran, and am wanting to read a txt file into a an array. I feel like I have tried everything. The txt file is comma seperated 11 rows with 1 number on each row.

Here is my code

```
program test

real:: obs1,i,jj,count,x_1
real,allocatable:: x(:)

open(1,file='data1.txt',status='old',action='read')
read(1,*) obs1 

allocate(x(obs1))

do i=1, obs1
read(1,*) x_1
x(i)=x_1
end do

do jj=1, obs1
print*,x(jj)
end do 

end program test
```

this is the error I am receiving:

```
The highest data type rank permitted is INTEGER(KIND=8)
```

Comment: I hope you have serious reason to use Fortran. It is... terrible, pre-historic, etc.

Comment: @i486: Why? Fortran is still actively developed, it is very elegant for numerical computations, compilers are typically more efficient in optimizing it than in optimizing C, etc.

Comment: It is developed by the corresponding "fan club". But I don't think that anything can be written in Fortran and will be more compact, has better readability, etc. with the same in C (except for the same Fortran "fan club").

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
allocate(x(obs1))
```

contains an error, though I'm not sure it's the one that matches the error message you report.  `obs1` is a `real` variable, but array dimensions (and indices) have to be integers.  Change the declaration of `obs1` to

```
integer :: obs1
```

Your compiler ought to complain about using a `real` variable in the do loop control too, `do i=1, obs1`.  Again, use an integer.

As an aside, since you are new to Fortran, learn to use `implicit none` in every scope within your programs.  SO will provide many questions and answers to explain what it means and why it is important, so will any of your favourite Fortran tutorials.